# How to connect cosmos DB using Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui, azure-cosmosdb

Wanted to make cosmos db connection on Azure through SoapUI groovy script.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

def END_POINT = 'https://XXXXXXXXX.documents.azure.com:443'
def MASTER_KEY = 'XXXXXiAdtwC12HmwrpE83I5zWS76T4FznonFQ2UV3EWJrqorIc6LkoDhvKkfa00XPHFyAtOKRLTHXFcWTD1g=='
def  databaseId = 'testdb12'
def collectionId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
Database databaseCache;
DocumentCollection collectionCache;

DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT,MASTER_KEY,ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),ConsistencyLevel.Session)
Database databaseDefinition = new Database()
databaseDefinition.setId(databaseId)
databaseCache = documentClient.createDatabase(databaseDefinition, null).getResource()
```

Error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator. (Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;Lorg/apache/http/conn/DnsResolver;)

I'm geetting error on this line

```
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT,MASTER_KEY,ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),ConsistencyLevel.Session)
```

I have tried with almost all the jar files.

Please add some valuable solution.